# Android In app purchase , credit card issue

Tags: android

I have integrated in app my Android app.
The app is saved as draft in Android market.
It has one product, which is published.
When I trigger the purchase, a screen appears asking for credit card info.
After entering the info, it says :

**An error occurred while saving your credit card. Please try again.**

I don't know what is the cause of this issue.
Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a test account?

> Test accounts are authorized to make in-app purchases from applications that you have uploaded to the Google Play site but have not yet published.

To add test accounts to your publisher account, follow these steps ([It's taken from official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html)):

1. Log in to your publisher account.
2. On the upper left part of the page, under your name, click Edit profile.
3. On the Edit Profile page, scroll down to the Licensing & In-app Billing panel
4. In Test Accounts, add the email addresses for the test accounts you want to register, separating each account with a comma.
5. Click Save to save your profile changes

Another thing, have you signed your app?

Comment: Yes I am using test account and I have mentioned it there. Also the app os signed. If both of these things are not done it doesn't brings till that page...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you fine. Then I don't know what could be happening. One more thing, quick idea ;), **Have you tried setting up the Google Checkout account online?**